# stop the highlighting of certain new programs Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

There are some programs that are highlighted in the start menu because I haven't used them yet.  I overall love this feature, but don't want it to apply to a few specific programs.

How do I turn it off?( ONLY for these few files)... Is there an option or something?

Comment: I believe it's all or none.  You can run those select few programs a few times, clearing the highlight.

Comment: They just go away after a while. But, if you want to make them go away, one would add a ROT13 encoded string of the application's path to the UserAssist registry key under under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\UserAssist. There would probably be a tool for this, but like I said, they  fade away after like a week anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For individual items that display in the start menu that you do not wish to show, right-click then click "remove from list." It should not display again.

If you do not want fresh installs to show up in the menu (have not used them yet):

1. On the Start button, bottom-left, right-click and select properties, click on the Start menu tab -> click on "Customize Start Menu."
2. Uncheck "highlight newly installed programs" (between Games and Music) then click "OK" then "Apply" then "OK."

[image: image of porp start menu]

For recently used items/ programs that do not show (they can show from other sessions even if not used in this one):

1. Click on the Start button -> right-click -> select "Properties."
2. Click on the Start menu tab -> in Privacy, uncheck the items you do not wish to have shown.

[image: image start menu prop tab]

Comment: Its not what I wanted... but I guess what I'm looking for doesn't exist.  Thanks anyway.